# Showing convergence using $\epsilon$-$N$ definition?

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{n+3}}$$

Using the $\epsilon$-N definition:

Fix some $\epsilon>0.$
Let $N = \frac1\epsilon$.

Where I'm confused, since this series converges to 0, would you continue by stating that $|A - 0| < \frac1n$ and continue from here, or in an analysis class would this be wrong?

Comment: Why do you choose $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$?

Comment: I'm new to this class and very behind, but isn't there some Archimedean Property (or some other property along these lines) such that you can take some (1/n)<epsilon? And therefore, because by the definition of convergence n>=N, (1/n)<=(1/N), so arbitrarily you can set N = 1/epsilon

Comment: That's confusing two seperate uses of $N$. In $N-\varepsilon$ proofs, $N$ is something else entirely, and not just $N=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no. The $\epsilon-N $ definition would be used as follows

Fix $\epsilon >0$. Show that:

$$\exists N \quad \mbox{such that} \quad n\geq N \Rightarrow |A_n -0| < \epsilon$$

Where $A_n$ is the sequence provided.

Here N can depend on $\epsilon$. Also to get some insight into what is actually happening, you are in effect saying that for large enough n, you are getting as close to the limit value as you want, even if you never reach it!

Hope this answers your query.

Some would define it like this also:
Fix $m \geq 1$. Show that:

$$\exists N \quad \mbox{such that} \quad n\geq N \Rightarrow |A_n -0| < 1/m$$

Comment: Thanks that actually makes a lot of sense

Comment: Your welcome. Do you need some tips on how to solve limit problems?

Comment: that would be appreciated

Comment: No matter the technique, its all about clever bounding of your sequence from above and below by sequences whose limits are known. Check out Squeeze theorem when you get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it by contradiction. Suppose that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $N\in\mathbb N$

$|0-{2\over {\sqrt{n+3}}}|$=$2\over {\sqrt{n+3}}$$>\epsilon$

For that $\epsilon$ there exists $m\in\mathbb N$ such that ${{1\over {m+1}}<\epsilon\leq{1\over m}}$ so we must have ${2\over {\sqrt{n+3}}}>{1\over {m+1}}$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$ and every $n\in\mathbb N$. Going further we get $2(m+1)>\sqrt{n+3}$. Choosing $n\geq 4m^2+8m+1$ we obtain a contradiction so the limit exists and the limit is $0$.